# how to control the appearance of a component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

**I want to control the appearance of a `Text` component**

In my code the `Text` component only appears only when a particular `Image` is rendered

This `Text` component should be visible after 5 seconds after the particular `Image` appears

**how can I do this here's my sample code**:

```js
renderImage1() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={require('./Images/image1.png')}
        style={styles.image1Style} >
        <Text         // I need to control this component's appearance
        style={styles.textStyle}
        onPress={() => this.setStep(2)}>
        Touch To Play
        </Text>
      </Image>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `<Image>` is component right? You can add `<Text />` component inside the `<Image />` component. So that it will display only Image component render.

Comment: right now its rendering both 
what I want is to show the image then after about 5 seconds show the text to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> right now its rendering both what I want is to show the image then after about 5 seconds show the text to the user

I could suggest:
1. Try using this.state to create display prop, that will use either boolean values (for if-statement) or "none" / "initial" values (for display Text style prop), or "visibile" / "hidden" values (for visibility Text style prop).
2. Set [timeout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) on this.setState({ showText: !showText }) function call.
3. And for **if-statement solution** make your render method render either Image with Text or without based on *this.state.display* truthiness or falsiness.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.display) {
        return <Image><Text></Text></Image>
    }
    return <Image></Image>
}
```

4. For **display or visibility soltions** use [ternary opertor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)  to fluctuate between [display](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/9d7e8e1a65-invisible-components-in-react-native) / [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) of your Text component in its styles:

Display:

```
<Text
    style={{ display: this.state.display })
/>
```

Visibility:

```
<Text
    style={{ visibility: this.state.visibility })
/>
```

Comment: thats an awesome answer thanks I thought that there is a prop for this otherwise this is the best approach